# Python unicode regular expression matching failing with some unicode characters -bug or mistake?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am attempting to use the `re` module in Python 2.7.3 with Unicode encoded Devnagari text.  I have added `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to the top of my code so all strings literals should be unicode objects.

However, I am running into some odd problems with Python's regex matching.  For instance, consider this name: "किशोरी".  This is a (mis-spelled) name, in Hindi, entered by one of my users.  Any Hindi reader would recognise this as a word.

The following returns a match, as it should:

`re.search("^[\w\s][\w\s]*","किशोरी",re.UNICODE)`

But this does not:

`re.search("^[\w\s][\w\s]*$","किशोरी",re.UNICODE)`

Some spelunking revealed that only one character in this string, character 0915 (क), is recognised as falling within the \w character class.  This is incorrect, as the Unicode Character Database [file on "derived core properties"](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/DerivedCoreProperties.txt) lists other characters (I have not checked all) in this string as alphabetic ones - as indeed they are.

Is this just a bug in Python's implementation?  I could get around this by manually defining all the Devnagari alphanumeric characters as a character range, but that would be painful.  Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a [bug in the `re` module](http://bugs.python.org/issue1693050) and it is fixed in the [`regex` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import unicodedata
import re
import regex  # $ pip install regex

word = "किशोरी"


def test(re_):
    assert re_.search("^\\w+$", word, flags=re_.UNICODE)

print([unicodedata.category(cp) for cp in word])
print(" ".join(ch for ch in regex.findall("\\X", word)))
assert all(regex.match("\\w$", c) for c in ["a", "\u093f", "\u0915"])

test(regex)
test(re)  # fails
```

The output shows that there are 6 codepoints in `"किशोरी"`, but only 3 user-perceived characters (extended grapheme clusters). **It would be wrong to break a word *inside* a character.** [Unicode Text Segmentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/) says:

> *Word boundaries*, line boundaries, and sentence boundaries *should not
>   occur within a grapheme cluster*: in other words, a grapheme cluster
>   should be an atomic unit with respect to the process of determining
>   these other boundaries.

<sup>here and further emphasis is mine</sup>

A word boundary `\b` is defined as a transition from `\w` to `\W` (or in reverse) in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re):

> Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a
>   \W character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of
>   the string, ...

Therefore either all codepoints that form a single character are `\w` or they are all `\W`.
In this case `"किशोरी"` matches `^\w{6}$`.

---

From [the docs for `\w` in Python 2](http://docs.python.org/library/re):

> If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [0-9_] plus
>   whatever is classified as *alphanumeric in the Unicode character
>   properties database*.

in [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re):

> Matches Unicode word characters; this *includes most characters that
>   can be part of a word in any language*, as well as numbers and the
>   underscore.

From `regex` docs:

> Definition of 'word' character ([issue #1693050](http://bugs.python.org/issue1693050)):
>
> The definition of a 'word' character has been expanded for Unicode. It now conforms to the Unicode specification at
>   http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/. This applies to \w, \W, \b and
>   \B.

According to [unicode.org `U+093F` (`DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN I`)](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=093F) is alnum and alphabetic so `regex` is also correct to consider it `\w` even if we follow definitions that are not based on word boundaries.

Comment: Yes, can confirm that regex module works.  The [[:alnum:]] POSIX character class also works with the regex module.

Comment: @ShankarG: `perl` agrees: `echo किशोरी | perl -CS -ne'print if /^\w+$/'` (assume utf-8 io).

Comment: Changed my "accepted" mark to this answer, since this is in fact the correct answer - it is indeed a bug in the re module.

Answer (score 2):

From Character Map:

> ‍ि
>
> U+093F DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN I
>
> General Character Properties
>
> In Unicode since: 1.1
> Unicode category: **Mark, Spacing Combining**

So, technically speaking this is not a letter and doesn't fall under `\w` even with `re.UNICODE`. You can try using [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) with Unicode character properties instead in order to include these sorts of characters.

Comment: According to the [list I linked to on derived code properties above](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/DerivedCoreProperties.txt) 093F is indeed classified as an alphabetic character.  Not sure what is going on.  In any case, these have to be recognised as such - these characters never stand on their own, they are modifications of existing characters to indicate particular vowel sounds (in this case the character indicates that the subsequent "ka" should be pronounced as a "ki").

Comment: If one were to reject these and similar charcters as alphabetical characters, no Devnagari text in any of the languages that use it (Hindi, Bengali, Marathi, etc.) would ever be recognised as alphabetical in nature.

Comment: "093E..0940    ; Alphabetic # Mc   [3] DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN AA..DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN II" Mc. **Mc**.

Comment: What does "Mc" mean? And doesn't it also say Alphabetic?

Comment: It's alphabetic, but *it's not a letter*.

Comment: And presumably being alphabetic is not enough to fall in the \w class? Sorry for the dumb clarifications, but I'm thoroughly confused...

Comment: It must have a category starting with `L` in order to be part of `\w`. This is why you use `regex` to catch other categories as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll try out regex in that case.  This is very useful to know, thanks for your answer.

Comment: `regex` module recoginizes `U+093F` as `\w`. see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12747529/4279)

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following:

```
import unicodedata
for c in "किशोरी":
    print unicodedata.category(c)
    print unicodedata.name(c)
```

which displays in my case:

```
Lo
DEVANAGARI LETTER KA
Mc
DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN I
Lo
DEVANAGARI LETTER SHA
Mc
DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN O
Lo
DEVANAGARI LETTER RA
Mc
DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN II
```

Unicode stuff is hard to debug because copy and paste can mess up the data and I don't know hindi. But in some languages you can encode characters in different ways in unicode. Is it possible, that you have to normalize your string  somehow before matching? To me it looks ok that a vowel sign is not matched by `\w`.

Comment: See comment on Ignacio's answer below.  What do you mean by normalizing, though?  Maybe that would do the trick.

Comment: I don't remember the exact details out of my head, but there a characters which exist on their own and can also be a cominbation. For example the german `ä`. It's a single character, but as far as I know there's a possiblity to encode it as `a` + `marker for having those dots over it`. And there's a transformation between both versions. Sorry, I have no possibility to check the details at the moment.