# Regex punctuation split [Python]

Tags: python, regex, string, split, punctuation

Can anyone help me a bit with regexs? I currently have this: `re.split(" +", line.rstrip())`, which separates by spaces.

How could I expand this to cover punctuation, too?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The official Python documentation has a good example for this one. It will split on all non-alphanumeric characters (whitespace and punctuation). Literally \W is the character class for all Non-Word characters. Note: the underscore "_" is considered a "word" character and will not be part of the split here.

```
re.split('\W+', 'Words, words, words.')
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html for more examples, search page for "re.split"

Comment: @dantdj So you want it to split on `'` and `"` and `*`, etc?  This answer does that. As in `My name's steve` will be split to `My name` and `s steve`.

Comment: @dantdj: to support Unicode [properly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12747529/4279), you could use [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). The usage is the same, just make sure the pattern and the string are Unicode: `import regex; L = regex.split(ur"\W+", u"किशोरी")`

Answer (score 27):

Using `string.punctuation` and character class:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> r = re.compile(r'[\s{}]+'.format(re.escape(punctuation)))
>>> r.split('dss!dfs^  #$% jjj^')
['dss', 'dfs', 'jjj', '']
```

Comment: word. this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
st='one two,three; four-five,    six'

print re.split(r'\s+|[,;.-]\s*', st)
# ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

Comment: how can you incorporate [ and ] in the list of [,;.-]

Comment: @O.rka Ask a new question if you have a new question.  But briefly, `[][,;.-]`

Answer (score 1):

When you consider using a regex to split with any punctuation, you should bear in mind that the `\W` pattern does not match an underscore (which is a punctuation char, too).

Thus, you can use

```py
import re
tokens = re.split(r'[\W_]+', text)
```

where `[\W_]` matches any Unicode non-alphanumeric chars.

Since `re.split` might return empty items when the match appears at the start or end of string, it is better to use a positive logic and use

```py
import re
tokens = re.findall(r'[^\W_]+', text)
```

where `[^\W_]` matches any Unicode alphanumeric chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/heu8nV):

```py
import re
text = "!Hello, world!"
print( re.split(r'[\W_]+', text) )
# => ['', 'Hello', 'world', '']
print( re.findall(r'[^\W_]+', text) )
# => ['Hello', 'world']
```