# How to build a regular vocabulary of emoticons in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-unicode

I have a list of codes of emoticons inside a file `UTF32.red.codes` in plain text. The plain content of the file is

```
\U0001F600
\U0001F601
\U0001F602
\U0001F603 
\U0001F604
\U0001F605
\U0001F606
\U0001F609
\U0001F60A
\U0001F60B
```

Based on [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex-in-python), my idea is to create regular expression from the content of the file in order to catch emoticons. This is my minimal working example

```
import re

with open('UTF32.red.codes','r') as emof:
   codes = [emo.strip() for emo in emof]
   emojis = re.compile(u"(%s)" % "|".join(codes))

string = u'string to check \U0001F601'
found = emojis.findall(string)

print found
```

`found` is always empty. Where I am wrong?  I am using python 2.7

Comment: Where's `string to check ` in your file? That's not supposed to be in `string`, I presume. Also, naming a variable `string` can be confusing, so you may want to refrain from doing so.

Comment: This is the string to catch `\U0001F601`

Comment: Then do `string = u'\U0001F601'`. Even better, use a different variable name, like `search` or something similar.

Comment: You right. This information is missing. python 2.7

Comment: Do you run into any errors? I think we need more information if we want to solve this problem.

Comment: No errors. Simply en empty list at the end  of the script. I am using a MacbookPro

Comment: More important is which version of python are you trying with - a string in python 3 is always Unicode but not under python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works with python 2.7

```
import re
with open('UTF32.red.codes','rb') as emof:
    codes = [emo.decode('unicode-escape').strip() for emo in emof]
    emojis = re.compile(u"(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape,codes)))

search = ur'string to check \U0001F601'
found = emojis.findall(search)

print found
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be doing fine in python 3 (just fix `print found` to `print(found)`). However, in python 2.7 it won't work, as its `re` module has a known bug (See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12747529/4241180) and [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue1693050)).

If you still need python 2 version of code, just use `regex` module, which could be installed with `pip2 install regex`. Import it with `import regex` then, substitute all `re.` statements with `regex.` (i.e. `regex.compile` and `regex.findall`) and that's it. It should be working.

Comment: Why do you think the bug is related to this problem?