# How to fix "nothing to repeat" regex error?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I know from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675144/regex-error-nothing-to-repeat) that, `nothing to repeat` in a regex expression, is a known bug of python.
But I must compile this unicode expression

```
re.compile(u'\U0000002A \U000020E3')
```

as a unique character. This is an emoticon and is a unique character. Python understand this string as `u'* \\u20e3'` and rise me 'nothing to repeat' error.
I am looking around but I can't find any solution. Does exist any work around?

Comment: If you mean you want to match those symbols literally, not treated as regex patterns, then you have an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has little to do with the question you linked. You're not running into a bug. Your regex simply has a special character (a `*`) that you haven't escaped.

Simply escape the string before compiling it into a regex:

```
re.compile(re.escape(u'\U0000002A \U000020E3'))
```

---

Now, I'm a little unsure as to why you're representing `*` as `\U0000002A` — perhaps you could clarify what your intent is here?

Comment: `u'\U0000002A \U000020E3'` is an emoticon. I must catch it in regular expression as a single character. Escaping it does not work. But when I try to compile it, 'nothing to repeat error' arise.

Comment: Thomas, OP reads them in from a file (the patterns are "dynamic"). This question seems to be related to previous OP's posts.

Comment: @emanuele while this character is represented as a single character, it's not technically a single character. That doesn't really matter though -- the issue might be elsewhere. Can you show how you use this regex and on what input?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Sure. This question is related to this other question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681364/how-to-build-a-regular-vocabulary-of-emoticons-in-python
I have a file that is a list of emoticons as ascii string. The ascii strings are representing unicodes strings.  My code breaks when * is present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use re.escape (as shown in "Thomas Orozco" answer)
But use it only on the part that is dynamic such as:

```
print re.findall( u"cool\s*%s" % re.escape(u'\U0000002A \U000020E3'),
               u"cool      * \U000020E3 crazy")
```