# Word Boundary regex does not match the whole word for Devnagari Script

Tags: regex, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

```
articles = ['a','an','the']
regex = r"\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(word))
sent = 'Davis is theta'
re.split(regex,sent)
>> ['Davis ', ' theta']
```

This snippet works with the English language but used with Devnagari scripts, it matches the partial word as well.

```
stopwords = ['कम','र','छ']
regex = r"\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(stopwords))
sent = "रामको कम्पनी छ"
re.split(regex,sent)
>> ['', 'ामको ', '्पनी छ']
```

**Expected output**

```
['रामको' 'कम्पनी']
```

I am using python3. Is it a bug or am I missing something ?

> I suspect /b matches [a-zA-Z0-9] and I am using unicode. Is there an alternative to this task?

Comment: @anubhava using regular expressions if possible. thanks

Comment: Check this: https://eval.in/1112028

Comment: @anubhava didn't work. ['रामको', '्पनी छ'] is not the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use this code using `findall` instead of `split`:

```
import re

stopwords = ['कम','र','छ']
reg = re.compile(r'(?!(?:{})(?!\S))\S+'.format("|".join(stopwords)))

sent = 'रामको कम्पनी छ'
print (reg.findall(sent))
```

This regex avoids use of word boundary which doesn't work well with Unicode text such as Devanagri.

[RegEx Code Demo](https://eval.in/1112051)

[Check: Python unicode regular expression matching failing with some unicode characters -bug or mistake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746458/python-unicode-regular-expression-matching-failing-with-some-unicode-characters)