# Having an issue in doing count Vectorization for Hindi Text

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, vectorization, countvectorizer

While Doing the count vectorization in Hindi, features names are getting automatically stemmed.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
test = []
test.append("हमें फिल्म बहुत अच्छी लगी ।")
test.append("फिल्म में कुछ बेहतरीन गाने हैं ।")
cv = CountVectorizer().fit(test)
print(cv.get_feature_names())
```

output: ['अच', 'बह', 'लग', 'हतर', 'हम']

Comment: What is your question? What output are you trying to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

The analyzer used by `CountVectorizer()` seems to badly support some encodings. You can define a custom analyzer, to define how to separate the words. To separate the words properly, you can use a regex:

```
import regex 

def custom_analyzer(text):
    words = regex.findall(r'\w{2,}', text) # extract words of at least 2 letters
    for w in words:
        yield w

test = []
test.append("हमें फिल्म बहुत अच्छी लगी ।")
test.append("फिल्म में कुछ बेहतरीन गाने हैं ।")
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer = custom_analyzer)
xv = count_vect.fit_transform(test)
count_vect.get_feature_names()
```

I used the [`regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) because it supports more encodings than the module `re` (Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12747529/8276531) for explaining).