# Is countvectorizer in sklearn only meant for English?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

I am trying to apply count vectorizer for Telugu and Hindi which are Indic language.But the vectorizer is stemming the words automatically.

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
xv=count_vect.fit_transform(['she is a good girl','वो बहुत सुन्दर है','ఇది చాలా లాడిష్ మరియు బాల్య టీనేజ్ కుర్రాళ్ళు మాత్రమే దీనిని ఫన్నీగా చూడవచ్చు', 'దోపిడీ మరియు ఎక్కువగా లోతు లేదా అధునాతనత లేని నేరాలకు సంబంధించిన గ్రాఫిక్ చికిత్సను చూడటం భరించదగినది'])
count_vect.get_feature_names()
```

the output is as follows:

```
['girl',
 'good',
 'is',
 'she',
 'दर',
 'बह',
 'అధ',
 'ఇద',
 'ఎక',
 'చదగ',
 'డట',
 'డవచ',
 'తనత',
 'నద',
 'ఫన',
 'భర',
 'మర',
 'రమ',
 'లక',
 'వగ',
 'సన']
```

It is clearly evident that it is stemming the telugu and hindi words automatically, is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analyzer used by `CountVectorizer()` seems to badly support some encodings. You can define a custom analyzer, to define how to separate the words. To separate the words properly, you can use a regex:

```
import regex 

def custom_analyzer(text):
    words = regex.findall(r'\w{2,}', text) # extract words of at least 2 letters
    for w in words:
        yield w

count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer = custom_analyzer)
xv = count_vect.fit_transform(['she is a good girl','वो बहुत सुन्दर है','ఇది చాలా లాడిష్ మరియు బాల్య టీనేజ్ కుర్రాళ్ళు మాత్రమే దీనిని ఫన్నీగా చూడవచ్చు', 'దోపిడీ మరియు ఎక్కువగా లోతు లేదా అధునాతనత లేని నేరాలకు సంబంధించిన గ్రాఫిక్ చికిత్సను చూడటం భరించదగినది'])
count_vect.get_feature_names()
```

I used the [`regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) because it supports more encodings than the module `re` (Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12747529/8276531) for explaining).